# Return names ranked based on two criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to return the name of the top N scorers given their

1. team played for and
2. position played. I've used `INDEX(MATCH(LARGE)` to return the top N scorer but haven't been able to successfully add IFS to the LARGE to create my criteria.This is my master list.

[image]

I want to find the highest value in colE given colD=KINGMANE and colC=D

In H21 I want to return the D from KINGMANE with the highest FPts. J19 is the team name,, colF is the position I want to look at, and colG is the rank I want to return.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax you're looking for the multi-conditional lookup based on rank would be the following. I'm assuming your range ends are 40 so adjust accordingly.:

`=INDEX([YourTable],MATCH(1,(LARGE($E$1:$E$40,1)=$E$1:$E$40)*($D$1:$D$40="KINGMANE")*($C$1:$C$40=[Position]),0),1)`

Breaking this down into references just plug in

`=INDEX([YourTable],MATCH(1,(LARGE($E$1:$E$40,[Rank #])=$E$1:$E$40)*($D$1:$D$40="KINGMANE")*($C$1:$C$40"[Position]),0),1)`